# Authlogic Perishable Token Resetting on Failed Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am using the perishable token magic in authlogic to do password resets.  However, it seems that the token is getting reset when a user tries to log in and fails.  This is because authlogic is incrementing failed login attempts on the user record.  So if the user requests a new password and then tries to log in before resetting the password, the perishable token changes.

Any ideas to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we eventually figured out a way around this.

First move was to disable the automatic perishable token handling:

```
#############
## Authlogic
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  .....
  c.disable_perishable_token_maintenance = true
  .....
end
```

Then we created our own before_filter on user to mimic the same functionality as the auto handler but ignore changes to the failed_login_count field:

```
before_save :handle_perishable_token

def handle_perishable_token
  unless failed_login_count_changed?
    reset_perishable_token
  end
end
```

This basically allows a user to fail at logging in and not reset the perishable token.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I like your solution, but in my opinion it's good to add:

```
before_save :handle_perishable_token

def handle_perishable_token
  unless failed_login_count_changed? && changed.size == 1
    reset_perishable_token
  end
end
```

because when you reset the password, between other attributes, failed_login_count is also changed (set to 0) and in this case perishable_token should be reseted.